# REFERENCES wrong table in case of @OneToMany relationship in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, backend

Got Exception while saving entity:

could not execute statement [Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails  (`demodbdev`.`itemimages`, CONSTRAINT `FKcdf6ngpc2Sr30p4V53v28obay` FOREIGN KEY (`itemss_id`) REFERENCES `itemtabletwo` (`item_id`))

Here 'itemtabletwo' is wrong referenced table, it should be 'itemtableone' as it is the primary key table where I am saving the data by calling default jpa repo method save.

Below are more details for your ref:

1-I have created a base class annotated with @MappedSuperclass for common properties, and created multiple child class entities using this base class, among them 'itemtableone' and 'itemtabletwo' are there.

2-While saving data to 'itemtableone' using jpa repo default method save() getting above exception where wrong REFERENCES table 'itemtabletwo' is added in the auto generated query.

3-'itemimages' is the table which is part of each table and used as below:

```
Unidirectional:
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "itemss_id")
private List<ItemImage> itemImages = new ArrayList<>();
```

-So my question is why the query is referencing(REFERENCES) the wrong primary key table name('itemtabletwo')?